# T-SQL get average based off same date last 4 weeks

Tags: t-sql, average

I have a table with results for everyday of the week for the past year. I need to get the average sales based off same day of the week(starting today) for the past 4 weeks. i.e. sales for every monday for the past 4 weeks.

What would be the best route? Any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your table structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straight forward, the only gotcha could be performance, which is why I'm isolating the the 28 day function so the cutoff date can be a SARG.

```
declare @cutoffdate datetime =  dateadd(day, -28, (DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)))

select avg(sales) as averagesales
  , datepart(dw, saledate) as saleDayOfWeeks
from your table
where saledate >= @cutoffdate
group by datepart(dw, saledate)
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.